# Catch cause of 'too many connections' in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql server which is occasionly returns the 'too many connections' error. I have worked with the server admin to set the mysql and server vars up to the best. We reckon it's down to a query which takes extremely long, then locks a table and thus backups others.

Was wondering what would be the best way to catch this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's not down to leaked connections? i.e. establishing a connection to MySQL and then not releasing it.

Comment: Number of connections are mostly always find. It just happens randomly which leads me to belive its a query which is occasionly called. But trying to locate this is a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to get to a terminal when you start running into this issue, run:

`SHOW PROCESSLIST;`

or

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`

Look for any queries that are taking their sweet time to finish that may be locking your tables.

However, 'too many connections' can also be a result of rogue code that is not properly closing the connections it is opening (as Dominic pointed out above).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried enabling the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html).  It's output can be very useful for catching these types of queries.